# Continuous function from $[0, 1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, continuity

> Let $f:[0, 1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a continuous function such that $f(0)=f
> (1)=0$ and we define
>
> $A=${$h\in[0, 1]|$ there exists $x$ with $f(x+h)=f(x)$}
>
> $B=${$h\in[0, 1]|$ there exists $x$ with $f(x+1-h)=f(x)$}
>
> Prove that $A\cup B=[0, 1]$.

I tried using the fact that $f$ is continuous but since $f$ has values in $\mathbb{R}$ it is a little bit more complicated. I assumed that there exists an $h\in[0, 1]$ sucht that none of the relations was true but I didn't managed to show anything.

Comment: My thoughts: Either $h\leq 0.5$ or $1-h\leq 0.5$. Assume WLOG that $h\leq 0.5$, and consider the function $g:[0, 1-h]\to \Bbb R$ given by $g(x) = f(x+h) - f(x)$. It ought to be possible to squeeze out some intermediate value theorem from this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easy to see that $0,1\in A\cap B$. Let $h\in (0,1)$ and consider the continuous function
$$g(x):=\begin{cases}
f(x)&\text{if $x\in [0,1]$,}\\
f(x-1)&\text{if $x\in [1,2]$.}
\end{cases}$$
then, since 
$$\int_0^1 (g(x + h) - g(x)) dx=\int_h^{1+h} g(x)dx - \int_0^1g(x) dx=0,$$ it follows that there exists $x\in [0,1)$ such  that $g(x+h)-g(x)=0$.

Now, if $x+h\leq 1$ then $f(x+h)=f(x)$ and $h\in A$.

On the other hand, if $x+h>1$ then $f(y)=f(y+1-h)$ for $y:=x+h-1\in(0,1)$ and $h\in B$.

Therefore we may conclude that $h\in A\cup B$.

Comment: How did you get that $f(1-h)<f(1)$ and also how did you justify existence of $x \in [0,1] $ satisfying the  last line in your proof?

Comment: @Erm20  He supposed that $f(x+h)>f(x)$